# Bind a simple integer array to a DropDownList in MVC3

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, integer, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

My ViewModel is as follows:

```
public class ClassificationCalculatorIndexViewModel
{
    public bool PlacementYear { get; set; }
    public int[] Credit { get; set; } // List of Integers
    public int selectedCredit { get; set; } // Somewhere to store selected integer
    public List<YearOfStudy> StudyYear { get; set; }
}
```

I am struggling to bind the Integer array to a DropDownList helper object in my Razor view, I am doing the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.selectedCredit, Model.Credit)
```

But getting errors, I tried Googling, but found nothing of the same nature :(

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The type arguments for method DropDownListFor<> cannot be inferred from the usage, try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need drop down for `selectedCredit` filled with items from `Credit` property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedCredit, new SelectList(Model.Credit))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `SelectList` object with the content of your `int[]`.